# Twitter Bootstrap 3 Carousel - display 2 pictures at a time rather than 3

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

Is it possible this `carousel` to display only 2 pictures at a time rather than 3?

Here is [working demo](http://www.bootply.com/94444).

I've tried to change columns to col-md-6 and css to 50% but with no luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove below lines from the javascript and change col-md-6

```
     if (next.next().length>0) {
    next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  `enter code here`}
      else {
        $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
      }
```

It works. Tested in your demo link